# Getting input from the same line of execution

Tags: perl, input, execution

So I'm trying to get an input from the user like this way: `user@server:~sample.pl input` so I used I do have this code

```
$input = <>;
chomp ($input);
print "$input";
```

but it doesn't serve the purpose that I want it to because the user will type the execution line `user@server:~sample.pl` then hits enter, THEN inters his input, but I don't want the user to hit enter.

I also tried

```
$input = `<>`;
chomp ($input);
print "$input";
```

but it crashed.

Hope I was clear in my question.

Thank you!

Comment: Format code blocks by indenting code by 4 spaces instead of using quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguments to Perl scripts are provided in `@ARGV`.

```
>perl -E"say for @ARGV" a b c
a
b
c
```

Comment: this is a small program, but the one I'm working on is huge, so I did try the `@ARGV`, but returned 1?

Comment: @Amture101 make sure to use parentheses `($input) = @ARGV`

Comment: Arrays in scalar context evaluate to the number of elements they contain. You need to evaluate it in list context to get a list of its elements. `my ($input) = @ARGV;`

Answer (score 1):

You want to read only the information that the user provides as arguments from the script. The `<>` operator will try to open any arguments supplied and will also read from `STDIN`, which is how the user is able to enter information after executing the script.

Arguments to a script are found in the variable `@ARGV` (with the character string split on whitespace), so you can use this to restrict the input to stuff typed in-line after the command:

```
print join(" ", @ARGV),"\n";
```

This example will echo whatever string of characters the user supplies.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Perl, there's another way to do it :-)

```
my $input = shift @ARGV;
```

Of course that only works if you only have one argument. Shifting off your data will get tedious after about two or three parameters, though.

If your parameters are well defined, you can do something like

my ($name,  $zipCode) = @ARGV;

and alternatively, if you want to ensure the user supplies all the parameters you can do something like

die "Usage: sample.pl [name] [zip]\n" unless $zipCode;

which does a quick-and-dirty check to see if the last parameter was entered (with absolutely no validation, but that's another topic).